# create multiple prefential attachment igraphs with increments on pa.exp

Tags: loops, nested-loops, igraph

I am trying to create multiple igraphs so far I only have:
`

```
set.seed(1)
   gs <- list()
   for (x in seq_len(100L)) {
   gs[[x]] <- sample_pa_age(10000, pa.exp=1.05, aging.exp=0.0, aging.bin=1000)
   E(gs[[x]])$weight <- sample(1:5, ecount(gs[[x]]), T)
   }
   plot(gs[[1]], edge.width = E(gs[[1]])$weight) # plot first graph
```

`
BUT what I want to do is to change pa.exp from=1 to=3 with an increment of .05., generating multiple graphs. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for loop:

```
pa <- seq(1, 3, 0.05)
gs <- vector("list", length(pa))
i <- 1
for(x in pa){
  gs[[i]] <- sample_pa_age(10000, pa.exp=x, aging.exp=0.0, aging.bin=1000)
  E(gs[[i]])$weight <- sample(1:5, 9999, T)
  i <- i+1
}
```

Alternatively, you can use lapply, so that you dont have to create the list beforehand:

```
my_graph <- function(x, n=10000){
  g <- sample_pa_age(n, pa.exp=x, aging.exp=0.0, aging.bin=1000)
  E(g)$weight <- sample(1:5, n-1, T)
  return(g)
}
gs <- lapply(seq(1, 3, 0.05), my_graph)
```